# Peer to peer with WebRTC and Flash fallback

Tags: flash, browser, webrtc

WebRTCs PeerConnection is gaining ground on Chrome, Firefox and Chrome Beta for Android. However the remaining browsers still need a fallback. Presumably Flash would work fine, since it incorporates peer to peer connections since 2010 roughly.

Is there a library containing utilizing WebRTCs PeerConnection and a fallback mechanism using Flash? If not, I'm interested in developing it myself. What would be the caveats when doing this?

I'm mostly interested in data transfers.

Comment: I'm aware of the polyfills below, but they don't really address your problem (I assume you're not interested in audio and video). For data only, you could build something with Socket.io but, of course, you'll need a server. The WebRTC codelab at http://bitbucket.org/webrtc/codelab might help. 
github.com/ShareIt-project/DataChannel-polyfill
github.com/addyosmani/getUserMedia.js

Comment: Thanks Sam. That DataChannel-polyfill might be a good solution. I also just now found ArcusNode, which uses the Flash RTMFP protocol and UDP. I *think* it uses UDP hole punching and then might suit my needs.